# printing specific item through a 3d list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I am trying to print out all the players rows of information who only play for the team "Okc", from my 3d list but I don't know how to do it.

The format of the list is like this: *[[Player, Position, Team, etc..], [Player, Position, Team, etc..], [Player, Position, Team, etc..]]*

```
import csv

f = open('nba-2019-20.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)

players = []

for row in reader:
    del row[6:10]
    del row[21:24]
    row.pop(7)
    row.pop(8)
    del row[9:11]
    row.pop(11)
    row.pop(12)
    players.append(row)

x = "Okc"

for dat in players:
    if dat[1] == x:
        print(dat)
```

Comment: And you want to keep it as a list ? Or a DataFrame is an option ?

Comment: `dat[1]` is *position*, so `if dat[2] == x` should do it, no? Otherwise, what's the problem exactly? You need to provide a [mre]. Also see [ask].

Comment: thank you wjandrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did it (if I understand what you want to do) - same as @wjandrea comment :

```
for dat in players:
    if dat[2] == x:
        print(dat)
```

As a list comprehension :

```
print([dat for dat in players if dat[2]==x])
```

Other solution is to do it in Pandas Dataframe (I'm assuming columns have names into the csv) and filtering on "Team" column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('nba-2019-20.csv')
print(df[df['Team'] == x]]) #returns a numpy series
```